# Oxyplot distance between ticks

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

How to decrease distance between ticks? I want to place candles more closely.
And i cannot find any property in `LinearAxis XAxis` that respond for distance.

[image]

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication20
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PlotClass();
    }

}
public class PlotClass
{
    public PlotModel PlotModel { get; set; }
    public PlotClass()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        PlotModel = new PlotModel();
        LineSeries LS = new LineSeries();
        LinearAxis XAxis = new LinearAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            MinorStep=1,
            MajorStep=1

        };
        LinearAxis YAxis = new LinearAxis()
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Left
        };
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            LS.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i,rnd.Next(1,10)));
        }
        PlotModel.Axes.Add(YAxis);
        PlotModel.Axes.Add(XAxis);
        PlotModel.Series.Add(LS);
        ChangeToCandles();
        WhatTypeOfSeries();
    }
    public void ChangeToCandles()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        PlotModel.Series.Clear();
        CandleStickSeries CSS = new CandleStickSeries();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++ )
        {
            CSS.Items.Add(new HighLowItem { X = i, Close = rnd.NextDouble(), High = rnd.NextDouble(), Low = rnd.NextDouble(), Open = rnd.NextDouble() });
        }
        PlotModel.Series.Add(CSS);
    }
    public void WhatTypeOfSeries()
    {
        var temp = PlotModel.Series[0].GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
    }
}
}
```

xaml:

```
 <Grid>
    <oxy:Plot Model="{Binding PlotModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try zooming:

```
XAxis.Zoom(-5, 15);
```

**EDIT>>>>**

You have a for loop from 0 to 10, you just have to add some adjust values. For that limits for being more generic:

```
int lowerIndex = 0;
int upperIndex = 10;
int zoomValue = 5;

for (int i=lowerIndex;i<upperIndex;i++)
{
    LS.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i,rnd.Next(1,10)));
}

XAxis.Zoom(lowerIndex-zoomValue, upperIndex+zoomValue);
```

Comment: It shoud not change distance between ticks.

Comment: I've tested it and it does, at least in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with `CandleStickSeries.CandleWidth` property:

1. If it is set to 1, then there will be no space between candles.
2. If it is set to value > 1, then candles will overlap.
3. If it is set to value < 1, then there will be a gap between candles. The smaller value, the bigger gap.